# Use a JSTL variable for JQuery attribute value

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a jquery code as follows for a datepicker.

```
$(function() {
    $('#fm-birthdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
});
```

This works file. Now what I have the user selected date format in the session.(Application is done by Spring 3.0). I want to use that value from session for the datepicker format. I tried as following.

```
<c:set var="currDateFormat" value="${dateFormat}" />

<script>
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "/static/images/calender.jpg",
    buttonText: "Calendar"});

    $(function() {
       $('#fm-birthdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: currDateFormat }).val();
    });
</script>
```

Nor working. Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo have to render the jstl var out into the javascript serverside so the javascript can't be in an external js file, it must be part of a jsp file.

You can do it like this using either `${dateFormat}` or `${currDateFormat}` as they are the same after you set the var.

```
$(function() {
       $('#fm-birthdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "${dateFormat}" }).val();
    });
```